# Effiective programming: How to use find_if without writing the actual predicate

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++98

Say i have the following definitions:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVec;
typedef std::set<std::string> StringSet;
```

and the following objects:

```
const StringVec& v
const StringSet& s
```

and I want to use `find_if` to find the first string in `v` that exists in `s`.

What would be my best course of action? Can this be done by binding some functions calls to avoid having to write a new predicate?

Edit: `s` is pretty big, so `find_first_of` is out of the question.

Comment: That would be really easy to do with a lambda... any special reason to avoid predicates?

Comment: I'm in C++98. No lambdas yet. only boost::bind and such. But I can't seem to make anything work without creating an actual class. I know that this can be avoided, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: BTW I saw you older question, and I was commenting when you deleted it: `find_if` returns the same iterator type as the range arguments, so you might try again knowing that.

Comment: My older question was starting an argument. I rephrased and started fresh.

Comment: Just write a plain loop.

Comment: I know I can, but I'm trying to start using recommendations from effective programming, and I want to start easy with this "easy" exercise...

Comment: I do like to use the STL algorithms. Sometimes though it's easier just to bite the bullet and write your predicate class. What's the point of squashing it all onto one line if nobody can understand the code? I got this far before I gave up: `std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind2nd(std::bind1st(std::ptr_fun(&std::find<std::set<std::string>, std::string>), s.begin()), s.end());`

Comment: @Shloim can you comment here the one you tried with `boos::bind`?

Comment: `StringVec::const_iterator itrFound = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind(&StringSet::find, s, _1) != s.end());`

Comment: Unless you plan a long-time relationship with C++98, you'd better learn the effective ways of the new C++ versions...

Comment: Waiting for company approval to make that change...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Your comments are not helpful.

Comment: I managed to make your code with `boost::bind` and `set::find` find compile, but its not returning the right answer IDK why

Comment: @NeilKirk: So ignore them. Maybe it's not for you.

Comment: @VillasV I know. I can't figure it out also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example based on your `set::find` with `boost::bind`:

```
const StringVec& v = {"a", "b", "z"};
const StringSet& s = {"c", "d", "z"};

StringSet::const_iterator (StringSet::*f)(const StringSet::value_type& val) const = &StringSet::find;

StringVec::const_iterator iter = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind(f, &s, _1) != s.end());

cout << *iter << endl;
```

The problem is that the `find` function has a `const` overload, so you have to make a cast inside the `bind` or use a `pointer-to-member` to specify which overload you want.

Also you must be careful to pass `s` by reference to the bind, otherwise it will copy the `set` and the `end` iterator returned will be different from the `end` iterator you're using in the comparison.

Comment: That did the trick! Now I found another option: `boost::bind(&StringSet::count, &s, _1) != 0`

Comment: True, `count` is also O(log n) for `set`... I usually forget that.

Comment: You can't portably take the address of member functions of standard library classes. The standard allows implementations to alter their signatures to their hearts' content as long as ordinary calls have the correct behavior.

Comment: @T.C. hmm that's interesting. So there's no safe way to `bind` with standard library functions? Is this method possibly leading to UB since the function I took might has been replaced?

Comment: @T.C. can you quote your source on that? I don't think it's true at all

Comment: @sehe [member.functions]/2. Footnote 188 is on point: *"188) Hence, the address of a member function of a class in the C++ standard library has an unspecified type."*

Comment: @Columbo Cool, thks. I didn't know that

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of). Even in C++11, that would be a better choice than `std::find_if` plus lambdas, because its name is a clearer indication of the code's intent and because it's just shorter and more concise.

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVec;
typedef std::set<std::string> StringSet;

int main()
{
    StringVec v;
    v.push_back("zero");
    v.push_back("one");
    v.push_back("two");

    StringSet s;
    s.insert("one");
    s.insert("two");
    s.insert("three");

    StringVec::const_iterator const find_it =
        std::find_first_of(v.begin(), v.end(), s.begin(), s.end());

    assert(find_it != v.end());

    std::cout << *find_it << "\n"; // prints "one"
}
```

Note that if your set is large, you *may* suffer from performance issues due to the algorithmic complexity of this approach.

Comment: The only downside is that each membership test is O(N), which could start to matter if the set was large.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Right. I'll add this. Thanks!

Comment: This is O(n*m). s is pretty big, I need it to be O(n*logm)

Comment: @Shloim: You should add this requirement to your question, then.

Answer (score 0):

another way, using boost::bind allow a flexible predicate without having to write a class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVec;
typedef std::set<std::string> StringSet;

namespace {

    bool contains(const StringSet& set, const std::string& s)
    {
        return set.count(s) != 0;
    }
}

StringVec::const_iterator search(const StringVec& vec, const StringSet& filter)
{
    using namespace std;

    StringVec::const_iterator it = std::find_if(vec.begin(),
                                                vec.end(),
                                                boost::bind(&contains,
                                                            boost::cref(filter),
                                                            _1));
    return it;
}

int main()
{

    StringVec v;
    v.push_back("hello");
    v.push_back("goodbye");
    v.push_back("echo");

    StringSet s;
    s.insert("a");
    s.insert("goodbye");
    s.insert("foo");

    StringVec::const_iterator it = search(v, s);

    static const std::string notfound = "not found";
    std::cout << ((it == v.end()) ? notfound : *it) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

of course, if you know that the `StringVec` is sorted you can reverse the algorithm and use a binary search for each item in the filter. This reduces the search time to better than O(N.logM) since we know that the search set is sorted as well, so we can discount all previous elements in the array that come before the lower_bound of a previous search:

```
StringVec::const_iterator search_sorted(const StringVec& vec, const StringSet& filter)
{
    using namespace std;


    StringVec::const_iterator best = vec.begin();
    for (StringSet::const_iterator search_it = filter.begin() ; search_it != filter.end() ; ++search_it)
    {
        best = lower_bound(best, vec.end(), *search_it);
        if (best == vec.end() || *best == *search_it)
            return best;
    }
    return vec.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this as a search of known words across several "corpora" (bodies of text).

The classical approach is to put the "dictionary" into a prefix-tree or "Trie" and match from that.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Here's a simple example using Boost Spirit's Trie implementation (`symbols<>`) as well as it's input stream matchers (`parse` with `istream_iterator`).

The program reads a dictionary <strike>from `/etc/dictionaries-common/words` (99k words)</strike> *from a hardcoded random-word dictionary (1000 words)* and puts them in a s Trie.

Next it reads all files named on the command line and displays the first match:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa5b7afd24f07931)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/directive/seek.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVec;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985525/effiective-programming-how-to-use-find-if-without-writing-the-actual-predicate 

    auto const& dict = [] {
        x3::symbols<x3::unused_type> dict;

        std::ifstream file("main.cpp");

        std::string line;
        while (getline(file, line) && line != "DICTIONARYSTART")
            ;
        while (file >> line && line != "DICTIONARYEND")
            dict.add(line)
            ;

        return dict;
    }();

    for (auto fname : std::vector<std::string> (argv+1, argv+argc)) {
        std::ifstream corpus(fname);
        corpus.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

        boost::spirit::istream_iterator f(corpus), l;

        std::string matched;
        if (parse(f, l, x3::seek [ x3::raw [ dict ] ], matched)) {
            std::cout << "first match in " << fname << " is " << matched << "\n";
        }
    }
}

#if 0
DICTIONARYSTART
fining attractions centripetal misanthropy duplexes Estella allusively battleship legging Charolais badmouthed mooning reptile soggy unethical conniver roadbed phlebitis feathering decrepitude dreariest mudguard capaciousness stroll devaluations
discomfiture boner cream Rachelle marine cornets earnest upshot degenerative hick collocation dowagers gangling synod petunia howdahs coils troubled squealed Oxfords counselors tinderbox latitudes robustly Gordon
economizing stagger encrusts neural vindication foaled nightclubbing case knot purling disciplinarian thatching ingrain rhymes flyweight wholesaler giggling displease catheters paradoxes miscellanies Valenzuela Gamble dykes judgemental
Tagalog wandering children classmates climactic workmanship Patricia fonder chubbiest cogitated Natchez tremendously dominated distemper castrating approbation Charles taproots head newsprint Quaalude unruffled Manaus legatees furrowed
rubberize ambience alleviated enthroning vermilion composure neglect fallibly Ike irks frostbite amnestying token playacted ligaments ancestral pureeing telepathy legrooms barrows solidified alumna Brazos inter Gogol
cups gesundheit brigs ordeals adulated gunboats Gatorade table Winnebago knit Cadillac indecision Florentine playgrounds houseplants trifler idolizing revile epitome berry candies whirred afterthoughts pickup tansy
maggots glazed mineralogists seeds iridescence tightness gusher product blackjack methodologies writes globetrotter hub allowances chronologically rid advantages breathe terrifyingly enormities dérailleur shame admission nosey bending
brogues mansion pursuits smell courtesy faulting plough oxygenate marinating customer OKs grayest cuttlefish showcased impunity stratifying elopes carefulness die amplifier Gobi exorcists then reediest bayberry
immure diligent enamors rapider presenter enhancements seasoning furnish Hilario glissandi holograph furor equably betrayer scavenger uncontested breastplate bicycling eclecticism Honduran hinted whitened coped noncommercial guileless
vinyl masonry desecrate kitchenware layouts degenerate reincarnating fondu Guinevere Kitchener reaffirms ploys fetchingly workings dictate debts porpoised skivvying Badlands posts contiguous runes bristling streak preempted
innovation landmasses reciprocates jigs crone permuted unkinder expectations meatloaves starters Aurangzeb paymasters thankfulness Brahms editions giveaways Salk Neogene indulged schoolbook summoner rerun monogrammed Sikhism protectorates
beholders tasseled Ebonics Antilles imbibed knobbiest Summer orthodontics parachutes overprices Harrods accessioned gatecrasher vents syncopates sects safeguards tulle Vitim cut living serest Hittite marshaling diffidence
nightshades sorted inputted parterres botching casually maturest cede backstopping misprinted calluses deflected crawlspaces spectroscopes freebases Goths cheapening avatar indulgence plumped sired titter longitudinally anthropocentric Tlingit
boaster Ptolemies Lohengrin vulgarest genealogist hammed missionaries fireflies imperatives sawyer boomed Alioth Godunov endocrines counterfeiter tradesman homicide basked unnaturally smudge intercedes putative wearies decisiveness serenades
pertain mists boating balked Maud ambulances actor interrogatory unravel marked rhetoricians possibility yardarm crankshafts queenliest jurist bitterns heavenward medulla binoculars outbreak adulates polythene Singleton reoccupied
trawl pyromaniac splendider booty demographer parlaying perpetration acacia removing mixtures reasonableness fastener Australia lanyards debate jurists prefabricating lorn revulsion constituents enrol nicknamed exclamations centigram stemmed
canniest bushels orchard obloquy Pat hooray foregrounds ordains firefight stylizes ladyfinger entity digestive similarities rigors nettled customized fission Marlowe ambassador easterlies sands wariness wretcheder sprinting
likewise somnambulist Bullwinkle Woolite stagnation covered affirmative beachhead warn snatching decreed middlebrow seediness nauseous bandaged Britney polysyllabic defray Cayuga intricately brassy culotte bidden wassail nudging
maidservants Clairol Panza apparition stagnate gardening unhurt skylarked affable constitutionally tamarind inception Haiti researches civics scroll unparalleled meats gaiter troop insult misapplied Cedric some coupling
sawdust jacket cautiousness distillers octane grainiest falls transliterates embezzler abrogation jimmies prodigy narrowed gunwales democratizing Fergus babysitters Bisquick blindside resettle phases infinitives overgrows painfully Sicily
otter croons whistles immortalizes gamed add uncover budding fink seizure Reichstag monsieur mayflies plumpest promptings wiggle crack scullion Boswell modernity Gloucester reprehending remarking trusting chewy
diabolically scants numeral providence norm fruity sprang sailboards analgesics intelligibility Gospels church arcade finder Berlioz subcontracting crawls imposing thruway baked philatelic Dobbin poltergeists perfectionist attainable
buses support Semite Saxon awkwardest Richie becalming Protestantism predicting pleaders novelist non adulteresses sadness privatizes Jayapura interfered recurs edgewise briniest Kirghistan retriever welcomed indispensables enthralling
recopies Brandy politicizing divining experiments Antaeus perfectible yak Wittgenstein Herder torn facetting supine spiritualism rickets stonewalled slaking duodenum horizontal chasuble boxed smelling trustees parallelled exonerating
numerals doctors diabolic bruskest artificers cauldron diapered hoarder stickiest overspend considered stranglehold animators pidgin overstay willingness Sade reenlisting internationalizing panicky introductions hostage alkali eligibility bleep
understood Claude Nile rebuilds Tatum tusk pantsuit subtlety scornful sequined bosuns meatiest synchronizes mammary cigarettes skinflint salved imbecility loyaler domiciling worshipped slugged breezing reemphasize astronaut
Jimenez Stockhausen Mickey claimants germane affordable zinging rapscallions debilitating undefeated amebas SARS prostrated Lynch sunflower inflicting grayer pancreas fishers mademoiselle trustful doorknob Melanesia interviewers Ken
subsections clewing shammy precedes chum seamed Guatemalan flaw plate Bergson photoelectric cite grandmas prisms chino temperatures stricken encroachment cheeps lampoons Wurlitzer exhumations dawdled pellets hard
kielbasas spaciously heedless transsexuals hither campaigning messiahs vows bloodhounds shrubbery admonishment weatherproofed suffusing fondness breakfasts McDowell fragrance morphine crisper demos fluoridated asphyxiated tango distorter lymphoma
sweat Marines articulated ripest seamanship disentangling underplay cares redcoats mommas groundlessly gondola vaporizer Lilliputian sinned overloaded lineaments commends symmetricly churlishness trimaran dizzies blacklisting artifices spunk
deteriorated piggybacked deliquescent unobstructed infinities descriptive veneered Izanami aphasia tariffs narrated hank notably fripperies pare Wyoming solemner unheard denseness autumnal obviates Arabia holstered sweeter misfortune
lurking newtons tattooist armada discomfit lodge mismanaging duchesses Gregg chorused Jeeves absolves gastric xylophones sandwiching unbinding overgrown upturn gloried ticker authentication bleeping duckling humbug pipe
gravitational enlightened classification percentiles cloys excoriate gibber encyclopedia Chi plaice skipped nought panoramic dovetailing washers amir lumpish advantaged seedling Eton skimps pathetically anus appetizing publican
impetuous Jungfrau ravens guffaw Buckner pained bids lockup Bronson cerise xerography pommeled riposted opportune offensiveness Maldives Roumania cuffs Baroda zeppelins extracting revising protrude shiver soberly
junipers evangelized monuments Atria Major predict afloat annoyance backspacing inadequacy oversampling desolated koshering reevaluated Rambo nope nickels receiving pricier undermining Damien minds vaccinating losses beyond
badmouths nudge picking flowerpots Geminis character blocks wrigglers mailboxes centerpieces inhibiting sofa breadfruit tawdriest sympathize unimpressed businessman strop atmospherically cankers headwind decaying Harvey nightgowns pullback
plagiarists Elohim supporter singularities treadmills kitchenettes malefactors Gauls Randolph phase Kristopher farce territorial antacids falsehoods callously elaborations furbelow joyous slipped windsurfs precluded beckoned huckster keyed
arbor grizzliest kinfolks frays rogered inevitable hula glibbest bloodmobiles Romero enlarge respective Skype premier reclaims densities retirements Emmanuel chaplains kaftans barbecues overworking prophecy thundercloud sequences
unmade recluses flout multicultural aggrandizement colic Pisa frescoes rescuing warpath Sakhalin ambiguous pliant foreclose malingerers cheeped titillate mete segmented sponsoring Oman sherry masqueraded sharpshooter windbreaker
sheepdogs collated lobbed glitzy romanticize quenched authenticity bolstering inconsolable executes mothball palpated archeological dilute Halley eschewing dispatcher newlywed snarl scolloping Kringle unchanged ransoming tendentious physiologist
DICTIONARYEND
#endif
```

It uses the Coliru code archive source files, and prints:

```
first match in /Archive2/1c/01a42044af380a/main.cpp is norm
first match in /Archive2/1c/02870c20800c0b/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/063e4e86b6f274/main.cpp is some
first match in /Archive2/1c/06764eac9f9c15/main.cpp is norm
first match in /Archive2/1c/09ceb6bfcce356/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/0af84db01a558d/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/0c69c1f71ab944/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/105f4dc87e9c37/main.cpp is inter
first match in /Archive2/1c/11dd8aa8f707f2/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/12d960b2f3cedc/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/14db343d423075/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/1b2dab88094b58/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/1c678972901e9a/main.cpp is case
first match in /Archive2/1c/1c94d656000dd3/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/2b2c872f6a0997/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/2cd15ce20cf655/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/2cffc4cb1e4833/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/2d97d3c8a41b49/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/2fb6dd2100093b/main.cpp is norm
first match in /Archive2/1c/3238c02de16b42/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/32ba2a7ce1a16b/main.cpp is inter
first match in /Archive2/1c/3a6a97e881cc7c/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/3c7526bf74e26e/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/40e751969aba85/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/43ceb4839799aa/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/4991da8c6646f4/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/4b6fe597df982b/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/4fb9bb993bc362/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/537e7a224dc57a/main.cpp is product
first match in /Archive2/1c/54220dff73afae/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/5480c8d4d62f98/main.cpp is cut
first match in /Archive2/1c/55888349cee769/main.cpp is case
first match in /Archive2/1c/569766d190c54b/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/5b12f271614992/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/5d49b8a392ff5a/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/607e23e7b226dc/main.cpp is inter
first match in /Archive2/1c/61f8330e834856/main.cpp is warn
first match in /Archive2/1c/644cd8af6fa664/main.cpp is cut
first match in /Archive2/1c/6a4d22e8e1e505/main.cpp is add
first match in /Archive2/1c/6d7c12e6a57a6d/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/6e3bde2c58f770/main.cpp is inter
first match in /Archive2/1c/6f738256e8c89a/main.cpp is inter
first match in /Archive2/1c/7052a20f642808/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/741e3ac097daa0/main.cpp is non
first match in /Archive2/1c/75dd2cfb00ab3d/main.cpp is table
first match in /Archive2/1c/7ab18d1d9ddd9d/main.cpp is table
first match in /Archive2/1c/7b7ca1e998bb64/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/7d7dd8dc289c16/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/7efbc7d4fce469/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/806c451005f8f7/main.cpp is inter
first match in /Archive2/1c/820d80113bc9e3/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/829b1d8678382b/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/83febbd048a14e/main.cpp is character
first match in /Archive2/1c/8412cafd7ee954/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/85eb2f5e332d00/main.cpp is pare
first match in /Archive2/1c/86fd186b34200e/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/8767373e2bf061/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/88f93c2a4010b7/main.cpp is support
first match in /Archive2/1c/8d3c351c8c6724/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/8faf4816d1b84c/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/9631ff5a6d5637/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/97f07d942dcd4f/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/9b3261d75ae2b6/main.cpp is some
first match in /Archive2/1c/9e4aae17e3c03d/main.cpp is add
first match in /Archive2/1c/9f2ced4e69425b/main.cpp is pare
first match in /Archive2/1c/9f4e0b93faa629/main.cpp is vents
first match in /Archive2/1c/a04b5230929695/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/a0829dfc522972/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/a29393ee55e157/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/a47ec51edba8cb/main.cpp is character
first match in /Archive2/1c/a55a6027325757/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/a7ebec0567e48f/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/a7fe7a320093c8/main.cpp is add
first match in /Archive2/1c/ab4fe7b5069d14/main.cpp is pare
first match in /Archive2/1c/af807c17c3ca60/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/afd70d2e07a8a0/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/b1c727cb701012/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/b7ac0cb452eb87/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/b85ce662d4855e/main.cpp is token
first match in /Archive2/1c/b9e74e0207d591/main.cpp is product
first match in /Archive2/1c/bb7ea3e28b6160/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/bbec68a3c55cc3/main.cpp is entity
first match in /Archive2/1c/c0a6faeac8f6b5/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/c28fe565ba3073/main.cpp is inter
first match in /Archive2/1c/c3ca4378cce289/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/c4192337c76a90/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/c59ec13eb3af37/main.cpp is then
first match in /Archive2/1c/c79ce6c11ee204/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/c9d2ca66a41568/main.cpp is Chi
first match in /Archive2/1c/cbb3b28241a4de/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/cea5bea5e1f536/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/d76b20ad2bc6bb/main.cpp is table
first match in /Archive2/1c/d91ec78cfa0059/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/d94170e5ae34a8/main.cpp is posts
first match in /Archive2/1c/d9ba600314aad8/main.cpp is inter
first match in /Archive2/1c/d9f38f5f33f3e4/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/dd455e8c517ad1/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/e44cf7524fe675/main.cpp is token
first match in /Archive2/1c/e493f86d2cb10b/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/e54afb138c7663/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/e8f3cb174be795/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/e92e50d612166f/main.cpp is add
first match in /Archive2/1c/f7d400828f0043/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/f7efe1f78fe0ec/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/fa2ebbcb27f03e/main.cpp is plate
first match in /Archive2/1c/fd9e7b68a370e5/main.cpp is add
first match in /Archive2/1c/ffb1009a22a1bc/main.cpp is plate
```

Comment: I coded this sample while live streaming, recording here: https://www.livecoding.tv/video/matching-dictionary-against-corpora-spirit/

Comment: Oops. Just noticed you said "c++98", well, here you go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/977cf008bbbee0c2 fully last-decade-proof